# Headless Home Server w/ Ubuntu Server - Resilio Sync - RClone

Tags: server, mini-pc

I would like to build a home server that runs Ubuntu Server with Resilio Sync and RClone. I think I can handle the software side but am having a hard time with the hardware side. I don't need wifi as I can plug it straight into my router (although I might decide to move it later so being able to add the capability might be nice). I would like it to be quiet since it will be in a living area. I would like it to be low cost maybe $200 to $300.

I would back it up to Google Cloud once a month with RClone. Most of the data will not be synced with other computers since a lot of it is for historical purposes or rarely used. Some of the data would need to be used with Resilio sync with selective sync for when we need the data on our other computers, this would be photos (over 12k and growing), movies, and some files. As Resilio Sync can be a bit of a resource hog when syncing 10s of thousands of files I will try to limit how many files it actually syncs but it will still be significant with the photos.

So, I need something that has decent processing power. Can upload relatively quickly and hold up to 200 G and growing amount of data (so, maybe 1 TB for now).

So, my needs aren't super great but I want to get something that will last 5 years or so, so I don't have to go through this again for a while.

Is there a place I can find a tutorial that will guide me through this? Many of the computers I'm finding seem to be overkill for my needs. I found this [Intel NM10 Black Mini](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16856205007) but they say it is loud. The NUCs seem like they are more than what I need.

Thanks ahead of time for any help/guidance on this topic.

**Update**

After looking at this more I've found an affordable Intel NUC that should serve my needs. Intel NUC NUC5CPYH

Comment: If you were to put the system together yourself it would bring down the cost massively. [PC Part Picker is great site for this](https://pcpartpicker.com/)